# xargs causing error when used to create directories?

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to create around 100 uniquely named directories that all contain a README.md file. I have tried doing this using the a text file, "PICOCTF.txt" containing:

```
vault-door-1
whats a net cat
strings it
Easy1
logon
13
caesar
dont-use-client-side
Bases
First Grep
So Meta
shark on wire 1
extensions
What Lies Within
la cifra de
picobrowser
asm1
Tapping
Flags
Based
Mr-Worldwide
plumbing
vault-door-3
rsa-pop-quiz
Client-side-again
Pitter, Patter, Platters
Web Gauntlet
asm2
m00nwalk
WhitePages
c0rrupt
vault-door-4
like1000
Guessing Game 1
droids0
mus1c
m00nwalk2
waves over lambda
messy-malloc
flag_shop
Investigative Reversing 0
asm3
miniRSA
vault-door-5
reverse_cipher
Irish-Name-Repo 1
shark on wire 2
Guessing Game 2
OTP Implementation
Investigative Reversing 2
droids1
Investigative Reversing 1
WebNet0
vault-door-6
seed-sPRiNG
Irish-Name-Repo 2
1_wanna_b3_a_r0ck5tar
b00tl3gRSA2
asm4
Irish-Name-Repo 3
JaWT Scratchpad
Java Script Kiddie
Need For Speed
Investigative Reversing 4
B1ll_Gat35
droids2
vault-door-7
AES-ABC
Investigative Reversing 3
vault-door-8
droids3
Java Script Kiddie 2
WebNet1
investigation_encoded_1
b00tl3gRSA3
john_pollard
droids4
Forky
investigation_encoded_2
sice_cream
B1g_Mac
zero_to_hero
```

On the command line and in the directory of the text file, I run the command to generate the directories:

```
xargs -a PICOLIST.txt -d '\n' mkdir
```

or (both have the same outcome)

```
while read -r line; do mkdir -p "$line" ; done < PICOLIST.txt
```

It does work in creating them, there is just one small problem. I realize it only creates the directory for know, but when I run it, I get files with a (null?) special character at the end. I don't know if this is a problem with the windows file system as I have formatted my text file to remove anything that would cause that issue (at least I thought). For ex:

This is before command is run:

[image]

This is after the command it run:

[image]

As you can see, there is a special character (asterisk? null byte? problem deciphering new line in xargs?) after every folder name...

My plan is to run the following code in the terminal but with this text file:

```
xargs -a PICOLISTFILL.txt -d '\n' touch
```

```
vault-door-1/README.md
whats a net cat/README.md
strings it/README.md
Easy1/README.md
logon/README.md
13/README.md
caesar/README.md
dont-use-client-side/README.md
Bases/README.md
First Grep/README.md
So Meta/README.md
shark on wire 1/README.md
extensions/README.md
What Lies Within/README.md
la cifra de/README.md
picobrowser/README.md
asm1/README.md
Tapping/README.md
Flags/README.md
Based/README.md
Mr-Worldwide/README.md
plumbing/README.md
vault-door-3/README.md
rsa-pop-quiz/README.md
Client-side-again/README.md
Pitter, Patter, Platters/README.md
Web Gauntlet/README.md
asm2/README.md
m00nwalk/README.md
WhitePages/README.md
c0rrupt/README.md
vault-door-4/README.md
like1000/README.md
Guessing Game 1/README.md
droids0/README.md
mus1c/README.md
m00nwalk2/README.md
waves over lambda/README.md
messy-malloc/README.md
flag_shop/README.md
Investigative Reversing 0/README.md
asm3/README.md
miniRSA/README.md
vault-door-5/README.md
reverse_cipher/README.md
Irish-Name-Repo 1/README.md
shark on wire 2/README.md
Guessing Game 2/README.md
OTP Implementation/README.md
Investigative Reversing 2/README.md
droids1/README.md
Investigative Reversing 1/README.md
WebNet0/README.md
vault-door-6/README.md
seed-sPRiNG/README.md
Irish-Name-Repo 2/README.md
1_wanna_b3_a_r0ck5tar/README.md
b00tl3gRSA2/README.md
asm4/README.md
Irish-Name-Repo 3/README.md
JaWT Scratchpad/README.md
Java Script Kiddie/README.md
Need For Speed/README.md
Investigative Reversing 4/README.md
B1ll_Gat35/README.md
droids2/README.md
vault-door-7/README.md
AES-ABC/README.md
Investigative Reversing 3/README.md
vault-door-8/README.md
droids3/README.md
Java Script Kiddie 2/README.md
WebNet1/README.md
investigation_encoded_1/README.md
b00tl3gRSA3/README.md
john_pollard/README.md
droids4/README.md
Forky/README.md
investigation_encoded_2/README.md
sice_cream/README.md
B1g_Mac/README.md
zero_to_hero/README.md
```

Both text files I am using were made in notepad++ set to "Unix (LF)"
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does`file PICOLIST.txt` print? Why does `PICOCTF.txt` occur in the question?

Comment: "file PICOLIST.txt PICOLISTFILL.txt"
returns:    
"PICOLIST.txt:     ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators"    
and    
"PICOLISTFILL.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators"

Comment: So they use CRLF.

Comment: I don't understand why though. Is it not set up to use Unix encoding?

Comment: I don't know Notepad++. *Maybe* `"Unix (LF)" modifications` make the tool insert LF when you type Enter, but does not convert CRLF terminators that are already in the file.

Comment: That makes sense I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothesis: `PICOLIST.txt` uses DOS/Windows line endings (CRLF, `\r\n`).

Both commands you tried (`read`, `xargs`) expect Unix line endings (LF, `\n`). They treat `\r` as a regular character. In your case `\r` is included in the string passed to `mkdir` each time.

Use `dos2unix` to convert the file.

If you must edit such file in Windows, use an editor that lets you choose Unix line endings. An editor with this ability can be used instead of `dos2unix` to fix the current file.

Possibly `PICOLISTFILL.txt` is similarly "flawed".

Comment: My bad, I should have added to my question: I am working in notepad++ and have already set it to use "Unix (LF)" modifications

Comment: dos2unix worked. Wish I knew why notepad++ didn't though! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to keep the txt files in original format you can prefix the xargs commands with:

```
cat PICOLISTFILL.txt | dos2unix | xargs ...
```

The xargs part won't need "-a" or "-d" flag if done this way.

Comment: Thanks, It's nice they can still be kept original.